# Installing a package from Makefile

Tags: makefile, fedora

I am a beginner in writing Makefile. I am writing one for building my first linux application.

I have written the following so far.

```
REDHATOS      := $(shell command -v cat /etc/redhat-release 2> /dev/null)
DEBIANOS      := $(shell command -v cat /etc/debian_version 2> /dev/null)
SWIG          := $(shell command -v swig 2> /dev/null)

PRE_BUILD_VALIDATION:
ifndef SWIG
    @echo "swig not installed, trying to install it first ..."
ifdef DEBIANOS  
    @sudo apt-get install swig
else
    @sudo yum install swig
endif
endif
```

Basically I want to check if [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (You can ignore this actually) is already installed in the system. If not, it will be installed first. I want to design the process platform-independent (Fedora or Ubuntu).

But, when I am `make`ing in a Fedora system, I am facing following error.

```
swig not installed, trying to install it first ...
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'PRE_BUILD_VALIDATION' failed
make: *** [PRE_BUILD_VALIDATION] Error 1
```

It should actually hit the `yum install swig` command as it's Fedora system. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help and please forgive if I am doing some stupid thing here. Beginner here !!!

Thanks !

Comment: `dnf install swig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're running `command -v`, which is documented like this:

```
-v  print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin
```

If you run it from the command line:

```
$ command -v cat /etc/debian_version
/bin/cat
```

So, both those variables contain the string `/bin/cat`, and neither one of them is empty so your `ifdef` is always true.

Probably you want to take out the `-v`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error here is that variables have wrong values.

Better use `wildcard` to check file presence:

```
REDHATOS      := $(wildcard /etc/redhat-release*)
DEBIANOS      := $(wildcard /etc/debian_version*)
```

Free tip:  :-)

```
ifneq($(DEBIANOS),)
 PKG_INSTALLER := apt-get
endif
```

Comment: Thanks. You gave me another way to do it.